# How to create a three line label: middle/ up + down

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-position

I have following label: 
 
[image: Lorem ipsum in line]

How do I make it so 'Lorem ipsum' reside **exactly in the middle** of two 'dolor' and 'amet'?
 
[image: Lorem ipsum in 3 lines] - rough picture

I tried:

```css
.gp-label {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}
.gp-left {
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 1px;
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.gp-right {
  float: left;
}

.gp-right,
.gp-right-up,
.gp-right-down {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div className="form-check user-select-none">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    className="form-check-input"
    id="gp"
  />
  <label htmlFor="gp" className="form-check-label gp-label">
    <div className="m-0">
      <div className="gp-left">Lorem ipsum &</div>
      <div className="gp-right">
        <div className="gp-right-up">dolor</div>
        <div className="gp-right-down">amet</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

But that results in:

[image: Lorem ipsum in 2 lines]
and I cannot force the first div to be middle.

I use Bootstrap 4 checkbox/label. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What are these `%` lines in your code? That's not valid HTML or CSS.

Comment: It's only description, some languages allow such comments. I will edit the question

Comment: Can you just use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` on the toolbar) please? that way it will run here on Stack Overflow and we won't have to do the copy/paste dance.

Comment: I've converted the code to a runnable Stack Snippet (and removed the meta commentary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using `flex`. Add it to your css:

```
.form-check-label.gp-label .m-0 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) is a more modern approach to this problem than floats. It's more flexible (pardon the pun). I also changed the position of the checkbox.

```css
.form-check {
  display: flex !important; /* defined as block by Bootstrap */
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}
.m-0 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}
.gp-left {
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 1px;
}
.gp-right {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.gp-right,
.gp-right-up,
.gp-right-down {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-check user-select-none">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    class="form-check-input"
    id="gp"
  />
  <label for="gp" class="form-check-label gp-label">
    <div class="m-0">
      <div class="gp-left">Lorem ipsum &</div>
      <div class="gp-right">
        <div class="gp-right-up">dolor</div>
        <div class="gp-right-down">amet</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```